How do I connect to an API without cors issues?
All I want is to receive data from an API but I get cors errors. I'm working locally. Here's the code:


// Fetch data from the Fantasy Premier League API
    async function getFPLData() {
    const url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/';
    
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);

        // Check if the response was successful
        if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        // Convert the response to JSON format
        const data = await response.json();

        // Log the data to the console or use it as needed
        console.log(data);

        // You can access specific parts of the data, e.g., players or teams
        const players = data.elements;
        const teams = data.teams;
        console.log('Players:', players);
        console.log('Teams:', teams);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('There was an error with the fetch operation:', error);
    }
    }



Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!
